# uiwebview not working with HTTP or HTTPS urls

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, info.plist

i am trying to load a url in uiwebview in xcode and it is loading just fine but problem is that there is ZERO user interaction with it. i can not touch any button on it or can not even scroll it. i have already tried `Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES` in info.plist but nothing happened here is my code.

```
[webPage setDelegate:self];
[webPage loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com"]]];
[webPage addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
```

here is more code from .h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webPage;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webPage;
```

its s simple uiwbview from interface builder in a simple uiviewcontroller.
and here is my info.plist

[image]

I figure out that problem might be here in this part of the code. there is a menu in my uinavigationbar as well which is loading xml menu. wait i will post my code.

```
- (void) makeMenu{
    @try {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0),^{
            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url/xml-menu.php"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
            if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
            {
                rssOutputData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                xmlParserObject =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:urlData];
                [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
                [xmlParserObject parse];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                sideMenu.delegate = self;
                NSInteger count;
                NSMutableArray *itemsArry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                count = [rssOutputData count];
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                    BTSimpleMenuItem *item = [[BTSimpleMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmltitle] image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]
                                                                       onCompletion:^(BOOL success, BTSimpleMenuItem *item) {
                                                                           [webPage loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmllink]]]];
                                                                       }];
                    [itemsArry addObject:item];
                }
                NSArray *itemSarry=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:itemsArry];
                sideMenu = [[BTSimpleSideMenu alloc]initWithItem:itemSarry addToViewController:self];
            });
        });
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }
}
```

when i call this method in viewdidload uiwebview stop responding. And if i do not call this part uiwebview works just fine. please help me i need this menu as well.

Comment: Have you removed your activity indicator after the page is loaded ??? Are you sure your activityIndicatorView is not blocking UI Interactions ???

Comment: activityIndicatorView is doing just fine i even tried without it but still the same

Comment: url schemes like http or https will not affect the userInteraction of native components buddy :) You are looking at the problem from a wrong perspective :) Can u please provide a little more code like how is your webView loaded ?? Is it added as a subView to some other VC ??? What delegates of webView you are handling and what you are doing ???

Comment: please view my question again i edited it.

Comment: Tried loading webView worked fine for me buddy :( Dont know what might be your issue

Comment: :( do you think this could be a issue on server side??

Comment: Try loading webpage in mobile browser if it is working fine then you cant blame server :) If its behaving the same in web browser as well then you know whos the culprit :P

Comment: What is the size of the xml response buddy ??? Is too huge ???

Comment: no not too huge just 10 to 15 entries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112140/discussion-between-sandeep-bhandari-and-vix-hunk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
webPage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: According to @Sandeep Bhandari comment, try to remove activityIndicator after loading.

Comment: I've just created a sample application with UIWebView and 

[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com"]]];

works fine